# Making asterisk look like a Kleene star

Tags: symbols

When I type `*` or `\ast` in LaTeX, it looks like this:

[image]

When I see other papers involving "Kleene closure", the asterisk looks like:

[image]

How do I obtain the second symbol? Searching for "Kleene star" or "Kleene closure" didn't yield any results.

EDIT:

The `\ast` symbol is overridden by the mnsymbol library. How can I tell it to use the default symbol but still keep the rest of the package for its other symbols?

Comment: Usually you get the second symbol by `\ast`. What else you are loading?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! The one you see really isn't the default. I think the default is the one you want. You must be using a different font or something like that, we really need to see what your set up is to be able to help you. Could you provide a really simple Minimal Working Example (MWE) http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that

Comment: Also check out `\textasteriskcentered`; then check out (it's on CTAN) *The Comprehensive LaTeX Symbol List*.

Comment: Your \ast is from the mnsymbol package.

Comment: @JohnKormylo you're correct, I was loading mnsymbol for vdots, udots, etc.. Is there a way that I can tell it to use the original symbol? Feel free to direct me to another question or resource on that.

Comment: Have you considered writing up front in your paper that a five-pointed star will be used to denote Kleene-closure? Can your readers be trusted not to get hung up over five-pointed versus six-pointed starts?

Comment: Of course, its not an actual problem, I just have some time on my hands and I find the default much more aesthetically pleasing.

Comment: @ChaseMeadors You have discovered why I usually discourage from loading `MnSymbol` just because it has more symbols available: it changes **all of them**! If your text font has a six pointed asterisk, it makes no sense at all that the math one is five pointed. See [Importing a single symbol from a different font](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14386/) and several other threads on the subject. In other words, you're asking the wrong question: the real one is “how can I import (list of symbols) from `MnSymbol`?”

Comment: @ChaseMeadors On the other hand, if your text font is Palatino, there would be no problem in having a five pointed asterisk: the Kleene closure is denoted by an asterisk and its typographic realization is immaterial.

Comment: The font guide http://www.latex-project.org/guides/fntguide.pdf was useful. The answer was baffling without it.